# cloudfountry mysql service config can modify?

Tags: mysql, cloud-foundry

I push my application(use mysql service) to cloudfoundry success.and use "vmc tunnel" access to the mysql service,and execute my sql file.
but I have a question, the mysql variable "ower_case_table_names" is default value 0. I want to set "ower_case_table_names=1". How can I do this?
the mysql service that provide by cloudfoundry can't be modify the settings?

need help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"lower_case_table_names" is a readonly variable and thus can't be set with the "SET" command. It's a server system variable which is set when mysqld is started. CF users do not have authority to change these system variables.

Comment: thanks, because when development, Some of the SQL statement didn't comply with the company standard(most develop on windows, and case-insensitive), so upload to cloudfoundry,some query occur errors.It seems can only modify the code...